# Having problems adding a cookie to my session

Tags: java, selenium, cookies

So basically; I found these 2 classes for creating a cookie and adding it to a session from some website because I don't know anything about cookies. I deleted some things from the code like "isSecured" because I thought it's unnecessary.
Creating the cookie is no problem but adding it to the session doesn't work, hopefully not due to the parts I deleted... But I really think they are unimportant.

Here is my whole class:

```
package indeed;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Cookies {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        System.out.print("input 1 for readCookie or 2 for writeCookie: ");
        input = sc.nextInt();

        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                readCookie();
                break;
            case 2:
                writeCooke();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("no");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void readCookie() {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.get("https://secure.indeed.com/account/login?hl=de&continue=%2Faccount%2Fview%3Fhl%3Dde");


        // Input Email id and Password If you are already Register
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-email-input"))).sendKeys("example@email.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-password-input")).sendKeys("examplepass");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-submit-button")).click();

        // create file named Cookies to store Login Information
        File file = new File("Cookies.data");
        try {
            // Delete old file if exists
            file.delete();
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
            // loop for getting the cookie information

            // loop for getting the cookie information
            for (Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
                Bwrite.write((ck.getName() + ";" + ck.getValue()));
                Bwrite.newLine();
            }
            Bwrite.close();
            fileWrite.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writeCooke() {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        try {

            File file = new File("Cookies.data");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String strline;
            while ((strline = Buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline, ";");
                while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String name = token.nextToken();
                    String value = token.nextToken();
                    String domain = token.nextToken();

                    Cookie ck = new Cookie(name, value, domain);
                    System.out.println(ck);
                    driver.manage().addCookie(ck); // This will add the stored cookie to your current session
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.get("https://secure.indeed.com/account/login?hl=de&continue=%2Faccount%2Fview%3Fhl%3Dde");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this particular problem myself by NOT using cookies but instead using the same instance of webdriver to avoid needing cookies in the first place

```
public static void switchToNewTab() {
    openNewTab();
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    getDriver().switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
}

public static void openNewTab() {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank');");
}

public static void firstRunWebpage() {
    getDriver().get("https://employers.indeed.com/p#post-job");
    getWait().until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-email-input"))).sendKeys("example@email.com");
    getDriver().findElement(By.id("login-password-input")).sendKeys("examplepass");
    //getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"label-login-rememberme-checkbox\"]")).click(); //typically already checked
    getDriver().findElement(By.id("login-submit-button")).click();
}

public static void afterFirstRun() {
    switchToNewTab();
    getDriver().get("https://employers.indeed.com/p#post-job");
}
```